# unable to add background color to my column in HTML document while using JSON2HTML library

Tags: python, html, json, json2html

I am converting a JSON file into HTML (which I am able to achieve) using "json2html" library . Apart from that, I am trying to add colorin one of the column depending upon the result. If it says true - I want the Background to be GREEN color , IF False, then RED color

```
import json2html


table = json2html.convert(json = data_to_be_sent)
report_html = table
```

Below is how my Output/HTML/report_html file looks like right now: All I want to do is add color to **'Success'** column depending upon the result

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,900" />

</head>

<body style="color: #333; font-family: Source Sans Pro;";>

<h2>Nightly Validation Report (2019/09/19, prod)</h2>

<h3>Nightly Validation Report (XX)</h3>

<br><br><table border="1"><tr><th>CorrelationId</th> 
<td>awsnightlyendtoend_XX_20190919T2319</td></tr><tr> 
<th>ValidationType</th><td>validate_adwactivityfact</td></tr><tr> 
<th>Success</th><td>False</td></tr><tr><th>OutputPath</th><td><ul><li><a 
href=https://XXXXX</a></li><li><a 
href=https://XXXXX</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><th>ValidationDetail</th> 
<td>Comparison Failed: matched=211009, missing=5, mismatched=0, percent success=99.9952609779446%</td></tr></table>


</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if `json2html` can add classes or styles to tags in HTML but HTML is a string so you can use ie. `.replace('<td>False</td>', '<td class="red">False</td>')` and then you can use CSS to set red color or `.red`

Comment: it seems you have two columns - first use `<th>` and second use `<td>` so you can add CSS `<style>td {background-color: red}</style>`  in string with HTML when you have `false` in JSON.